# How to route a form post to PHP file from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I already have a php file that takes the contents of an html form that I've now converted to Rails. I don't want to rewrite the php in rails but I'm having issues posting to it. I put the php file in the public directory and can access it if I type the address directly but when I submit a form with it as the action rails serves a 404 not found. How do I tell Rails to serve it from apache?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you show the form tag you're using (at at the very least), so we can see the location to which you're POSTing the form.

Comment: I'm developing the site with Radiant CMS so the form is just html: <form action="contact.php" name="input" method="post">